# Configure patched module in jboss eap 7

Tags: jboss-cli

We use eclipselink in our applications therefore we configured JBoss to use eclipselink as persistence provider. We configured this by putting the eclipselink.jar into the following path:

> JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main

In addition we have changed the `module.xml` accordingly. After that we could use it and it worked fine.

Now we want to configure the jboss with a command line script to avoid manual work. In addition the jboss should be patched to the current patch level (jboss eap 7.0.7).

After applying the patch the eclipse persistence module is in the following path:

> JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.7.CP/org/eclipse/persistence/main

With a later patch the path could be different therefore we don't want to copy files in absolute paths.

Is it somehow possible to use the jboss-cli to configure this module (add jar and change `module.xml`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
module add --name=MODULE_NAME --resources=PATH_TO_RESOURCE --dependencies=DEPENDENCIES --module-xml=YOUR_MODULE.XML
```

> --module-xml    - (used with add, optional) filesystem path to the module.xml
>                      file which should be used for the added module. The file will
>                      be copied to the created module's directory. If this argument
>                      is not specified, module.xml file will be generated in the
>                      new created module's directory.

MODULE_NAME should be org/eclipse/persistence/main in your case

Comment: We use the `module add` command for other modules and that work. But with the eclipselink module we want to change an existing module. In addition the eclipselink module was patched by Redhat and it does not reside in the `modules/system/layers/base` (=default) path.